# How to open a series of websites at once whose URLs differ only by a letter?

Tags: google-chrome, url

Suppose I have a website which has the attendance of every student at a school. The URL for that page where the attendance for the child with roll number 01 is something like this:

```
www.school.com/attendance/01
```

Then, for the next roll number, the URL is this

```
www.school.com/attendance/02
```

and so on...

I have to open thirty such pages. I think there must be a quicker way to do this than to manually feed them in the address bar.

Comment: Add them to an app that automatically converts an URL to a clickable link (e.g., Word), then click each in turn.

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't an application, you are able to execute javascript by typing it into the Chrome omnibar. For example, putting the following into the omnibar will open www.school.com/attendance/01 to www.school.com/attendance/30

`javascript:for(var i=1;i<=30;i++){window.open("http://www.school.com/attendance/"+(("0"+i).slice(-2)));}`

Note that you will have to type in the `javascript:` manually and make sure your popup blocker is disabled.